# mlogit (subscript) logical subscript too long

Tags: r

I was trying to use `mlogit function` in `R` to estimate a nested `logit` model. And there is a nest with only one alternative. Therefore, I have to use the '`constPar`' to let the function know that this nest has `parameter '1'`. But I encounter the error:

> Error in attr(x, "gradi")[, !fixed] :    (subscript) logical subscript
>   too long

I dont know why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. It seems that the package 'mlogit' get updated on 4/20/2018. They changed the format of the parameter.
previous: iv.nest_name
now: iv:nest_name
So when we use the constPar parameter, we have to follow the new format. The manual they provided is outdated.